# How to return information from a cell on another sheet that is in the same row as the one being edited?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to be able to return information from a cell on another sheet but I want the information that is returned to be on the same row that is currently being edited. The trigger should be the drop down list. The drop down list is on the same row as the information I want to be returned on the other sheet.

My spreadsheet is set up like this

| . | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | info here |  | Drop Down |
| A2 | info here |  | Drop Down |
| A3 | info here |  | Drop Down |

Other sheet IF formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Form Data'!C:C,"Save"),'Form Data'!A1)
```

The problem is here that the if formula is only going to populate the information from a1 from c1 and will not populate if the drop down in c2 was to change to "Save" as it will return C1.

The drop down list should only ever have one "save" option at a time when working on the sheet. Is there a way that I can return the information from column A depending on whatever cell in column c changes to "Save"?

I hope I explained this well.

I have tried different If formulas and I cannot figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: VLOOKUP isn't good?

Comment: Im getting a #REF error with vlookup

Comment: Hi Black Cat, thank you for your suggestion.

I have done that but I still seem to be getting the #REF! error